# Adding slider to header in wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to add slider to header part in a word press static page. How to do it?I have gone through various plugins but all of them require to alter the code in header.php.Some one please help me with this and show me a way to do it.What other plugins do i need to enable the slider effect?
 In drupal we need

> jquery.cycle.js

Do we need such kind of file in wordpress as well??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install whichever slider plugin you want to use and add images to it. Find the shortcode to embed it onto a page, it will be something like `[slideshow id=1]`. To add that to the `header.php` file add the following code to where you want it displayed:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[slideshow id=1]'); ?>
```